# How to install sublime text on ubuntu chromebook?

Tags: chromebook, sublime-text

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 on my samsung chromebook using crouton. I wanted to know how can i install sublime text on it (any version would do) ? And if it is not possible to install it then please recommend some nice alternative to it.

this is the error log when installing:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sublime-text
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 9,670 B of archives.
After this operation, 51.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu/ precise/main sublime-text all 2.0.2-1~webupd8~3 [9,670 B]
Fetched 9,670 B in 3s (2,521 B/s)       
Preconfiguring packages ...
Please report to author unsupported platform 'armv7l'.
Selecting previously unselected package sublime-text.
(Reading database ... 68361 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking sublime-text (from .../sublime-text_2.0.2-1~webupd8~3_all.deb) ...
Please report to author unsupported platform 'armv7l'.
Please report to author unsupported platform 'armv7l'.
Downloading...
--2014-05-26 10:21:44--  https://c758482.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime%20Text%202.0.2.tar.bz2
Resolving c758482.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com (c758482.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com)... 72.246.79.162
Connecting to c758482.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com (c758482.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com)|72.246.79.162|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5584673 (5.3M) [application/x-bzip2]
Saving to: `Sublime Text 2.0.2.tar.bz2'

     0K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 56% 23.3K 1m42s
  3072K ........ ........ ........ ........ .....            100% 56.3K=2m54s

2014-05-26 10:24:45 (31.3 KB/s) - `Sublime Text 2.0.2.tar.bz2' saved [5584673/5584673]

Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch Sublime Text 2.0.2.tar.bz2
Sublime Text is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/sublime-text_2.0.2-1~webupd8~3_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/sublime-text_2.0.2-1~webupd8~3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Chromebook's are ARM, aren't they? Sublime doesn't run on ARM..

Comment: So which one should i use .

Comment: You  can't run sublime as it's not  build for ARM processors - see http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/100806-armv7-or-armv6-version-of-sublime-text-2-for-linux/.

Comment: @mreq - your's is the correct answer - please answer it and then Anurag can & should mark this as the correct answer.  There is very little point in having the current answer marked as accepted when it is very clearly wrong.

Comment: There are many chromebooks now which are not ARM. I bought a chromebook this week and almost all the ones I saw are using intel Celeron processors. I can't speak to you samsung chromebook specifically, but the response that chromebooks are ARM and can't run sublime is too general. Many can run sublime now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't run sublime as it's not build for ARM processors.

ARM builds [are wanted](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/100806-armv7-or-armv6-version-of-sublime-text-2-for-linux/), but not available.

Comment: intel has gained a significant majority market share in chromebooks as of august 2015. I doubt OP still uses his chromebook from 2013, but people who bought chromebooks more recently should check and see if their chromebook is intel before seeking alternatives to sublime

Answer (score -1):

I found this way to solve this problem:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg
mv info info.bak
mkdir info
```

Then install again.

Answer (score -2):

Just do these steps below and it should get you the app.

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Comment: i tried this but i got an error. Here is my log - http://paste.ubuntu.com/7518639/

Comment: I installed on mine and it is working well and good :)

Comment: On chromebook ?? but how. anyways could please suggest some other alternative to it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know if chromebooks were arm. As for alternatives, you may try geany, gedit, vim, nano. I hope you've tried gedit, it's good on its own. I have written many c programs with it.